# Resize rectangle with four corners using fabric js

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    rect = {
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        w: 123,
        h: 58
    },
    handlesSize = 4,
    currentHandle = false,
    drag = false;

function init() {
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function point(x, y) {
    return {
        x: x,
        y: y
    };
}

function dist(p1, p2) {
    return Math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y));
}

function getHandle(mouse) {
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'topleft';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'topright';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottomleft';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottomright';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w / 2, rect.y)) <= handlesSize) return 'top';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x, rect.y + rect.h / 2)) <= handlesSize) return 'left';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w / 2, rect.y + rect.h)) <= handlesSize) return 'bottom';
    if (dist(mouse, point(rect.x + rect.w, rect.y + rect.h / 2)) <= handlesSize) return 'right';
    return false;
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    if (currentHandle) drag = true;
    draw();
}

function mouseUp() {
    drag = false;
    currentHandle = false;
    draw();
}

function mouseMove(e) {
    var previousHandle = currentHandle;
    if (!drag) currentHandle = getHandle(point(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop));
    if (currentHandle && drag) {
        var mousePos = point(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
        switch (currentHandle) {
            case 'topleft':
                rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                rect.x = mousePos.x;
                rect.y = mousePos.y;
                break;
            case 'topright':
                rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                rect.y = mousePos.y;
                break;
            case 'bottomleft':
                rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                rect.x = mousePos.x;
                rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                break;
            case 'bottomright':
                rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                break;

            case 'top':
                rect.h += rect.y - mousePos.y;
                rect.y = mousePos.y;
                break;

            case 'left':
                rect.w += rect.x - mousePos.x;
                rect.x = mousePos.x;
                break;

            case 'bottom':
                rect.h = mousePos.y - rect.y;
                break;

            case 'right':
                rect.w = mousePos.x - rect.x;
                break;
        }
    }
    if (drag || currentHandle != previousHandle) draw();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
    if (currentHandle) {
        var posHandle = point(0, 0);
        switch (currentHandle) {
            case 'topleft':
                posHandle.x = rect.x;
                posHandle.y = rect.y;
                break;
            case 'topright':
                posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w;
                posHandle.y = rect.y;
                break;
            case 'bottomleft':
                posHandle.x = rect.x;
                posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h;
                break;
            case 'bottomright':
                posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w;
                posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h;
                break;
            case 'top':
                posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w / 2;
                posHandle.y = rect.y;
                break;
            case 'left':
                posHandle.x = rect.x;
                posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h / 2;
                break;
            case 'bottom':
                posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w / 2;
                posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h;
                break;
            case 'right':
                posHandle.x = rect.x + rect.w;
                posHandle.y = rect.y + rect.h / 2;
                break;
        }
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(posHandle.x, posHandle.y, handlesSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    }
}

init();
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

This link contain the example of what I need in fabric js to resize the rectangle area with fixed corner without get in on hover as example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BaliBalo/9HXMG/

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish such in the following way ...

- set `lockMovementX = true` and `lockMovementY = true` to prevent movement of the rectangle object
- disable the corner controls to prevent corner resizing of the rectangle object *(which makes it fixed corner)*

```js
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
let rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: '#07C',
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  hoverCursor: 'default'
});
canvas.add(rect);

// prevent movement
rect.lockMovementX = true;
rect.lockMovementY = true;

// prevent corner resizing
rect.setControlsVisibility({
  tl: false,
  tr: false,
  bl: false,
  br: false,
  mtr: false
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: resize of rectangle should be corresponding to mouse pointer position and not just simple drag in some direction.

Comment: In above example it just resize in some aspect ratio not in mouse pointer's position.

Comment: @RobsonJohny what do you mean by `mouse pointer's position` ?

Comment: If you try to resize the rectangle in example what i have posted,it just resize corresponde to the mouse pointer.(i.e :Resize Shape of rectangle corresponde to the mouse pointer area position inside the canvas any were.But in fabric rectangle resizing in some aspect ratio without corresponde to mouse pointer area position)

Comment: Thanks for the response.But,i think i didn't explain correctly the last time.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But,i think i didn't explain correctly the last time.In the example above what i posted, When you mouse down or click one of the corner of the resize handler and drag to any point inside the canvas ,the corner of the rectangle comes along with the position of mouse pointer without getting away from the mouse pointer.
but, in fabric js When you mouse down or click one of the corner of the rectangle and drag to any point inside canvas it resize and not to the position of the mouse pointer anywhere inside canvas.@moáois

Comment: (In above answer example When you click and drag the bottom handler it moves up and downwards
but while moving towards left to the canvas it resize only towards up and down.)   @moáois